# R sample.split(large vector) takes forever

Tags: r

I have a data table with 3,640,000 observations (55.5 MB) and three columns. I am trying to split this data into a training set and a test set to build a simple linear regression model. Here is my code.

```
library(caTools)
set.seed(123)
split <- sample.split(datasetSubset$TOTAL_POS, SplitRatio = 0.75)
training_set <- subset(datasetSubset, split == TRUE)
test_set <- subset(datasetSubset, split == FALSE)
```

sample.split is taking forever (I tried running for several hours, didn't finish). Any idea how I can create a training set and a test set?

**What finally worked?** 
I had difficulty [installing the caret package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35444753/r-error-installing-caret-package).

Solution proposed by @aginensky worked.

Also the following worked (as suggested by Alex who is a Teaching Assistant on Udemy)

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
library(tidyverse)
datasetSubset$id <- 1:nrow(datasetSubset)
train <- datasetSubset %>% dplyr::sample_frac(.75)
test  <- dplyr::anti_join(datasetSubset, train, by = 'id')
```

Comment: > foo = matrix(rnorm(3640000*3),nrow = 3640000)
> beg = Sys.time()
> idx = sample(3640000,round((3640000*.75)))
> train = foo[idx,]
> test = foo[-idx,]
> Sys.time() - beg
Time difference of 0.622014 secs

Comment: indexing is usually really fast.  In addition, if you use the caret package it has a function for splitting data into train/test that preserves the numerical characteristics of the dependent variable.

Comment: `caTools::sample.split()` tries to preserve the relative ratios of different labels in the dataframe. Do you have a lot of unique values in any/all of your columns? If there are a lot of unique labels the function may be working hard to preserve the relative ratios of those labels. Do you really need to preserve these? Or can you use a random distribution like the default splitting function in Caret.

Comment: The dependent variable (POS $) has a lot of unique values. The other two columns (categorical variables) don't have too many unique values and are numerically encoded. I am trying to install the caret package. Installed fine, but library(caret), is giving a weird error. I will be sure to come back and update this thread.

Comment: KalC - Did you consider simple rowwise indexing as @aginensky suggests? No packages needed.

Comment: @Parfait  Yes it worked. 2.092209 secs. aginensky  - I'd be happy to mark it as an answer.

Comment: @KalC I will do so.  One style suggestion - pos, while probably an abbreviation for position, has a distinct and very different meaning as an abbreviation.